# Moving items to list of items in an Entity Framework migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using Asp.Net MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6. I've got a table like this:

```
public class Recipe
{
    [Required]
    public virtual Food Food { get; set; }

    //...rest
}
```

Now I want to move the `Food` to a list of foods. Like this:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public virtual IList<Food> Foods { get; set; }

    //... rest
}
```

If I try this and add a migration, I'll lose the data related to `Food` Ids. And won't know which recipe is for which food.

I tried keeping the `Food` and add the list like this:

```
public class Recipe
{
    [Required]
    public virtual Food Food { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Food> Foods { get; set; }

    //... rest
}
```

But the migration adds a second foreign key and fails to update. Here's the migration code that fails:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Recipes", "Food_ID", "dbo.Foods");
        DropIndex("dbo.Recipes", new[] { "Food_ID" });
        AddColumn("dbo.Foods", "Recipe_Id", c => c.Int());
        AddColumn("dbo.Foods", "Recipe_Id1", c => c.Int());
        AlterColumn("dbo.Recipes", "Food_ID", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.Foods", "Recipe_Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Foods", "Recipe_Id1");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Recipes", "Food_ID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Foods", "Recipe_Id", "dbo.Recipes", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Foods", "Recipe_Id1", "dbo.Recipes", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Recipes", "Food_ID", "dbo.Foods", "ID");
    }
```

How can I move the single `Food` to a list of `Food`s without losing the current data in the table?

Comment: What was the original relationship between `Recipes` and `Foods`? Looks like you're trying to go from a one-to-one (where the foreign key is in the `Recipes` table) to one-to-many (where the foreign key is in the `Foods` table)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to customize your migration after creating it.

1. Modify your entity class

   > ```
   > public class Recipe
   > {
   >     public virtual IList<Food> Foods { get; set; }
   >
   >     //... rest
   > }
   > ```
2. Use `Add-Migration` to scaffold the migration
3. Modify the generated migration to fill the new column with data. You'll want to fill the new `Recipe_Id` column in `Foods` with the IDs of the previously related rows.

   ```
   public override void Up()
   {
       DropForeignKey("dbo.Recipes", "Food_ID", "dbo.Foods");
       DropIndex("dbo.Recipes", new[] { "Food_ID" });
       AddColumn("dbo.Foods", "Recipe_Id", c => c.Int());

       // Update values from existing data, not sure if the syntax is perfect
       Sql(@"UPDATE dbo.Foods SET Recipe_Id = r.Id
             FROM (SELECT Id, Food_ID FROM dbo.Recipes) AS r
             WHERE Foods.ID = r.Food_ID");

       DropColumn("dbo.Recipes", "Food_ID");
       CreateIndex("dbo.Foods", "Recipe_Id");
       AddForeignKey("dbo.Foods", "Recipe_Id", "dbo.Recipes", "Id");
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked flawlessly. Only correction: `WHERE Foods.ID = r.Food_ID` in your `UPDATE` statement.